# why i can't see all the folders of the google glass when i connect it to my laptop?

Tags: google-glass

i have a problem with my google glass. When i connect it to my laptop i can't see all the folders that should be there. 
Normally when you connect an android device all the folders appear in your lapton.

The only two folders that appear are : "DCIM" & "Pictures". There should be other folders as well when i connect it to a PC.

Moreover, when i connect the google glass to my laptop via cmd, i do ls, and all my folders are there.

Does anyone has any idea?

thanks,
daniel

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general Glass support rather than programming. https://www.glass-community.com/ is a better fit for this question.

Comment: Hi guy! Can you tell me how do you see file syste through cmd (what commands do you use? I can't see it T_T